# Cannot edit DataGridView cell, after choosing option I have to press Esc and lose the edit

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2012, datagridview, combobox

So here is the story - I have 2 `DataGridViews` - one of them is used as a display, the other one is user for editing or adding new entries. I don't use bindings on the `edit` one. When I am creating new entry I am just extracting the cells' values and passing them to an object. When I am editing though comes the problem.

The edit consists of 2 parts - one is to select the entry to be edited and display it on the second `DGV`. This is done with `SelectionChanged` event and the code is bellow. Then when editing is done it should just publish the new task the same way as creation. The thing is that when I am doing the edit and I come to the moment when I have to select from one of my cells - a `ComboBoxCell` - and I make a selection everything freezes. I cannot click anything else than this `ComboBox` until I press `Esc` - which obviously reverts the choice.

Why is this freeze happening and what causes it only when the data is cloned from the first `DGV`, but is okay when creating a brand new row? I am using VS2012 by the way and this is a windows forms application

Here is the code for duplication of the selected task - this method is the only thing in the `DGV1`'s `SelectionChanged` Event handler:

```
public void createTemplateTaskToBeEditted(Form1 form1, ApplicationControl appControl)
    {
        form1.dg_templateView.Rows.Clear();
        for (int i = 0; i < form1.dg_taskView.SelectedRows.Count; i++)
        {
            if (form1.dg_taskView.SelectedRows[i].Cells[0].Value == null)
            {
                form1.dg_taskView.SelectedRows[i].Cells[0].Value = false;
            }
            int index = form1.dg_templateView.Rows.Add();

            form1.dg_templateView.Rows[index].Cells[0].Value =
                form1.dg_taskView.SelectedRows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString();

            form1.dg_templateView.Rows[index].Cells[1].Value =
                form1.dg_taskView.SelectedRows[i].Cells[2].Value.ToString();

            form1.dg_templateView.Rows[index].Cells[2].Value =
            form1.dg_taskView.SelectedRows[i].Cells[3].Value.ToString();

            form1.dg_templateView.Rows[index].Cells[3].ValueType = typeof(ComboBox);
            form1.dg_templateView.Rows[index].Cells[3].Value =
                    form1.PopulateAssignToComboBox(appControl.GetAllowedMembers(form1));


            form1.dg_templateView.Rows[index].Cells[4].Value =
                    form1.dg_taskView.SelectedRows[i].Cells[5].Value.ToString();

            form1.dg_templateView.Rows[index].Cells[5].Value =
                form1.dg_taskView.SelectedRows[i].Cells[6].Value.ToString();

            form1.dg_templateView.Rows[index].Cells[6].Value =
                form1.dg_taskView.SelectedRows[i].Cells[7].Value.ToString();

            form1.dg_templateView.Rows[index].Cells[7].Value =
                form1.dg_taskView.SelectedRows[i].Cells[8].Value.ToString();

            form1.dg_templateView.Rows[index].Cells[8].Value =
                form1.dg_taskView.SelectedRows[i].Cells[9].Value.ToString();

            form1.dg_templateView.Rows[index].Cells[9].Value =
                form1.dg_taskView.SelectedRows[i].Cells[10].Value.ToString();

            form1.dg_templateView.Rows[index].Cells[10].Value =
                form1.dg_taskView.SelectedRows[i].Cells[11].Value.ToString();

            form1.dg_templateView.Rows[index].Cells[11].Value =
                form1.dg_taskView.SelectedRows[i].Cells[12].Value.ToString();
        }
    }
```

Comment: You should post relevant code. The loop is incomplete and we don't see anything wrt the events that are there.

Comment: I have literally copied the whole method now. This is responsible for duplicating the values from `DGV1` to `DGV2`. `GetAllowedMemebers` is just returning a list of items(and is properly populated into the `ComboBox` with the `PopulateAssignToComboBox` - again, only adding to the `ComboBox`. What other code would you like to see, so that I can add it ? The item selection of the duplicated `ComboBox` is where the issue starts.

Comment: _this method is the only thing in the DGV1's SelectedRow Event handler_ I have never heard of such an event. Do you mean `SelectionChanged` or what?

Comment: Excuse me.. it is `SelectionChanged`.. i will edit my question as well